# MinGW gfortran LAPACK dgsev

Tags: gfortran, lapack

I want to use the LAPACK library in my fortran code. I am compiling using gfortran and want to call the dgesv function from the lapack library.

I downloaded lapack3.5.0 and built it using Cmake which also tests it. The build for lapack3.5.0 has created the following libraries: libblas.a, liblapack.a, libtmglib.a

I am using a make file to compile my code using gfortran.

How do I use these libraries with gfortran compiler, I get error of dgsev being undefined when I compile. I have added the path to these libraries to the system path.

I have no clue what to do to use external libraries in gfortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `-L` option of `gfortran` linker. Using this you will point the compiler to look for libraries in this path.

For example:

```
gfortran test.f -L/path/to/libs -llapack -lblas
```

If you have additional libraries you can setup like this

```
LLIBS  = -L/path/to/libs -llapack -lblas
XLIBS  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lX11 -lpthread 
GLIBS  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lXext -lpthread
OBJS   = test.o
gfortran $(OBJS) $(LLIBS) $(XLIBS) $(GLIBS)
```

There is no need to add anything to system path.

Comment: This works, thanks. Can you please also help me how to add it to my make file. I have several subroutines that I am compiling using using a make file. My make file has libraries `XLIBS  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lX11 -lpthread `
`GLIBS  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lXext -lpthread`    how can I add these libraries to my make file?